# Start a script with systemd when user logs in

Tags: scripts, login, systemd

I'm trying to start a script with systemd, when an user logs in. Nevertheless until now, it is not working the way I'd like.
What I did:

I placed the following service in `/etc/systemd/system/loginNordVPN.service`

```
[Unit]
After=network.service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script `/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN` has this content:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Script for automatic login at nordvpn
set timeout 10
set username "myusername\r"
set credentialpass "mypassword\r"

spawn nordvpn login
expect "Email / Username: "
send "$username"
expect "Password: "
send "$credentialpass"

interact
```

The script `/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN` works, if I start it with `./autologinNordVPN` (independent, whether I start it with a normal user or as user with sudoers right).

After booting the machine and logging in as user with sudoers right, I can connect to NordVPN - the service above executed the script. Fine until here.

If I log in as "normal" user without sudoer right, I cannot connect to NordVPN - so something went wrong. Therefore I tried to add the service above to the users systemd. I copied the loginNordVPN.service to `~/.local/share/systemd/user/` and I started the service with `systemctl --user enable loginNordVPN.service`. (I also removed the service from the systemwide systemd before.)

After reboot and login it seems, that the script wasn't executed totally.

If I look into the journal with `journalctl --user | grep "nordv"` I can see, that service was startet, but for what ever reason it doesn't work:

```
journalctl --user | grep "nordv"
Dez 13 15:04:03 MYSYSTEM systemd[3497]: Started Login current user to nordvpn.
Dez 13 15:04:03 MYSYSTEM autologinNordVPN[3503]: spawn nordvpn login
```

I tried to change the user service this way, which does not work:

```
[Unit]
Description=Login current user to nordvpn

[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And this try neigther works:

```
[Unit]
Description=Login current user to nordvpn

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

What do I have to do, to get my service with the script working for any user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but now this works - `~/.local/share/systemd/user/loginNordVPN.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Login current user to nordvpn
After=network.service
After=network-online.target
#Requires=nordvpnd.service

[Service]
#StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN
#TimeoutSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Of course I enabled and started the service.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit file probably needs a dependency on `nordvpnd`, the daemon that seems to actually connect to the NordVPN network and configure the VPN interface.

A line such as `Requires=nordvpn.service` in the `[Unit]` section of your unit file should do it.

What happens if you define `/etc/systemd/system/loginNordVPN.service` as:

```
[Unit]
Description=NordVPN Auto Login
After=network.service
After=network-online.target
Requires=nordvpn.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/autologinNordVPN

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And `systemctl enable nordvpnd`?

Comment: Hi @renatoc, Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately your idea did not work.

The nordvpnd was enabled before systemwide. Therefore I can use the nordvpn commands in the terminal and they are working.

I tried to add `Requires=nordvpn.service` as well as `Requires=nordvpnd.service` in the way you suggested. If I do that and start the service in `--user` context I am getting an error like this:

:~$ systemctl --user enable loginNordVPN.service
:~$ systemctl --user start loginNordVPN.service
Failed to start loginNordVPN.service: Unit nordvpn(d).service not found.

Any other idea? Thx